# Is it possible to get gold points for games purchased before signing up for My Nintendo?

Tags: my-nintendo

I bought about $200 worth of digital games before signing up for My Nintendo and I want/*need* the gold points.  Does anyone know how to get them for games I bought before I signed up?

Comment: I strongly suspect that you'll only be able to get the points for things purchased after you sign up.